# How to build qemu tcg plugin?

Tags: plugins, qemu

Qemu documentation provides how to run qemu plugin , But i want to know how to build inbuilt plugins in qemu meson.build exixsts in plugin folder but how to create .so files of plugins in qemu

How to compile plugin in qemu

Comment: I am able to solve it , go to contrib/plugin and run make file